# Hook for API function GetSystemMetrics

Tags: c#, windows, api, compact-framework, windows-ce

Please help me create hook for AP.I function GetSystemMetrics.
I want that when some app(for example calc.exe) call GetSystemMetrics they receive my value(for example 500x500) and other apps get correct screen size.
And if somebody can tell me how can I do this use C# and .net CF 2.0 I'll be very happy.

Thanks and hope for you help.

Comment: [Why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, even in native code (at least not without ugly, bad-idea, vtable/kernel memory hacks that may or may not continue to work across versions of the OS).  GetSystemMetrics calls down to the OS to get information about the platform.  There's no way, short of recompiling the OS and changing those values, that you can "override" thse values and get the OS to report other numbers (unless, of course, the OS was already built in such a way that those numbers came from somewhere your app can modify - like the registry).

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, your actual problem is that you're trying to create some form of "taskbar" type application and you'd like other apps outside of your control to not overlay your taskbar when they maximize.  This is exactly how the exisiting Explorer taskbar works, so my suggestion is to go look in the default shell source code and see how it is accomplished there.

The end result is likely going to be that you will either clone the existing shell code and modify the existing taskbar to meet your needs, or you'll create an entirely new shell application that has the behavior you want, but you almost certainly are going to have to replace the shell, and that can only be done with native code.

Comment: Sure you can do it; it's just going to be terrible.

Comment: Maybe I can create somethin like screen region and run this app in this region/sandbox?

Comment: If you're trying to create a custom "task bar" type thing, you really just need to write a shell replacement.

Comment: @ctacke few apps after runing have size FULL screen and task bar hide bottom part of their window because this apps use GetSystemMetrics for getting screen size.

Comment: Then rebuild the kernel and have it respond with the size you want.

Comment: @ctacke I was changed screen resolution in kernel but in this case wince get wrong resolution and they think that my screen have smaller resolution and didn't see all screen. I need something that send only for one app custom resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do in C#/.NET without writing any native code. However, the good news is that there is a wonderful library called madCodeHook which is really easy to use. Take a look at http://madshi.net/